# How to handle a full CircularBuffer in C++

Tags: c++, serial-port, buffer

This is a general question, I am newbie to C++ and I am playing with a project that reads data from serial/usb ports in a worker thread at 1 msec intervals into a circular buffer, and I have another GUI UI thread that grabs data every 100 msec. What happens when data gets backed up and the data buffer gets full, I don't want to be blocking, I need to grab the data as it comes no waiting. What are common practices in such scenarios? Do I create another buffer for the "extras", or do I make original buffer bigger?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on which implementation of circular buffer you use. You can block the insertion if it's full, or you can erase the first element (and then the second, etc...)

Comment: Decouple data processing from your GUI thread.

Comment: I think this is in some ways data specific. Can you afford to drop data and still continue? I think the bottom line is you either block or you report an error condition. Then its up to higher level code how to deal. Having a second buffer sounds like a complicated way of having a bigger buffer to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it bluntly, you are screwed.

Now, let's look at how bad things are, there are multiple ways to treat overflow of a buffer:

1. Drop some data, optionally silently. You have to decide whether dropping data from the start or the end works better.
2. Merge some data to free space in the buffer.
3. Have an emergency-buffer at hand to catch the overflow.
4. Abort the operation, things must be redone completely.
5. Ignore the error and just pretend it cannot ever happen. The result might be interesting and quite unexpected.
6. Re-design for faster hand-off / processing.
7. Re-design with a bigger buffer for peak-throughput.

Anyway, if you want to read more about it, look into realtime and soft-realtime programming.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. #1 is absolute No, I can't drop one bit of data! #3 is the first thing off top of my head like I mentioned in my op. Can you elaborate on #6?

Comment: @sam2015 Not much can be said about #6, I'm afraid. Implementation specific. Basically, get data out of the buffer and into the hands of the consumer faster and have the consumer process the data faster so that the consumer can grab more data from the buffer. Both depend almost entirely on how your program moves and uses data. Only advice that can be given is general performance tuning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a circular buffer that allocates more memory when it's full.

If you're not interested in creating your own circular buffer, you can use [boost's one](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html), or just check it as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would put this in a comment, but since i can't:Is there a reason why you cannot adjust your buffersize?

If not i dont see any reason why you should not use your buffer to give you some safetyspace here, afterlall that's what buffers are made for.